# Trying to use Greasemonkey to create a button that can run Javascript. 

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Website I'm on has a bunch of chat rooms that can be accessed via a dropdown menu. Problem is the Dropdown menu is generated via VBScript while the buttons themselves are Javascript. I have no problem using Internet Explorer, but a friend of mine really needs to use these rooms and cannot as she is on a mac. I'm trying to create a Greasemonkey script that will create these buttons elsewhere on the page so she can actually click on them, but I have no experience with Greasemonkey or Javascript at all.

When I right click a button in IE and choose Properties this is the code it gives me. I hope this is what you'd need to help, if not please let me know and I'll try to get what you need.

```
javascript:OpenWindow('/Portal/ChatTransfer.aspx?
chatroom=ATTNesting1&url=https://chat02.arise.com/chat/
','','width=800px,height=600px,status=no,menubar=yes,
scrollbars=yes,titlebar=no,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no');
```

Comment: Clarify.  You use the menu, then a button appears, then you click that button for the chat?  Your friend can see the menu, but the buttons don't appear?  We need the code from the menu.  Please either (A) link to the page, or, if that's not possible, (B) save the page's source to a file and upload that to [pastebin.com/](http://pastebin.com/).

Comment: Brock, the menu expands down from a smaller button when moused over and has several buttons for many different chat rooms. On IE the window pops out just fine, provided I run it in compatibility mode for IE7. On Firefox the menu button shows up, but will not expand downward. On Chrome and Safari the menu button won't appear at all. Safari running in Develop mode IE7 will show the menu button, but the menu will not expand downward. Page link won't help as it's password protected. Pastebin tells me the source code file is too large.

Answer (score 4):

In short...

```
// create button
var btn = document.createElement( 'input' );
with( btn ) {
  setAttribute( 'onclick', 'alert( "you clicked me!" )' );
  setAttribute( 'value', 'click me!' );
  setAttribute( 'type', 'button' );
}

// append at end
document.getElementsByTagName( 'body' )[ 0 ].appendChild( btn );
```

This should add  a button at the end of the page; of course you have to replace the `alert()` in the onclick-attribute with your desired `OpenWindow()`-function call. And I guess you have to address it with `unsafeWindow.OpenWindow()`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply wonk0. Tried that and I can get the button that gives the "You clicked me" alert, but trying to paste in the OpenWindow function makes the button disappear entirely. Guess I just don't know my way around coding it. Thank you for trying to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Another much-easier option is to make **bookmarklets**; bookmarks that execute javascript. Simply create a bookmark with each of the `javascript:` URLs and add `void(0);` to the end. Then you can click the bookmarks to do the actions.